Error mounting/dev/sdb1 at/media/ tizibienvenus/Seagate
Unable to access Seagate Expansion Drive
Error mounting/dev/sdb1 at/media/ tizibienvenus/Seagate Expansion Drive: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on/dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.


Your question and answer mention /dev/sdb1 but the error message is about /dev/sdd1.

I had the same error with my hard drive in Ubuntu 24.04, updating and re-installing ntfs-3g solved the issue.
